# Get OperationFailure error with PyMongo 2.7.1

Tags: pymongo

I run into an OperationFailure error with PyMongo 2.7.1 with the following code:

```
db.business.update(
   {'_id': ObjectId(business_id)},
      {
        '$set': {'photos.primary': photo_url},
        '$push': {'photos.secondary': old_primary_url}
      }
)
```

I get the following error, when the primary member already has a value

```
<class 'pymongo.errors.OperationFailure'>: '$set' is empty
```

Has anyone an idea to tackle this?

Best

Comment: Can you show us your document? Also did you use `pymongo.Connection` to connect to running mongod instance?

Comment: Sorry, I did not close the issue. As far as I can remember, it was a config issue.